# I don't care about the non stick property of a non stick pot. Is there any harm in washing it in a dishwasher?

Tags: non-stick

I have this T-Fal non stick pot, and really I don't have any use for the non stick coating. I'm wondering if there's any harm in washing it in the dishwasher aside from the non-stick coating wearing off. In particular I am wondering about food safety.

[image: pot]

Comment: Hello Mike, the health effects of ingesting PTFE are not something we can discuss here, see http://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. Instead of closing, I removed the part about health effects, as it is possible that it will have culinary effects. But if answers veer into health claims, they will have to be removed.

Comment: @rumtscho the help article you linked doesn't clearly indicate that health effects of this sort are off topic. The closest example of an off-topic question describes a health question about a specific food. And an on-topic bullet point notes cooking equipment questions.

Comment: You have misunderstood it. Health effects of any sort are off topic, described as "general health [...] issue". This is one of the strictest rules here. We cannot evaluate whether what you are putting into your body deserves the label "healthy".

Comment: Please do not edit to turn this into a health question. If you do, we will have to close it.

Comment: How is a potential safety issue arising or not arising from continued use of damaged equipment not a food safety issue?

Comment: @rackandboneman food safety refers to "what to do to not get an infectious illness when eating". It only encompasses disease which can be traced to its origin with relative ease, such as getting salmonellosis after you ate old eggs. It does not extend to stuff which might or might not change your chance of contracting an illness which is related to, but not exclusively caused by environmental factors. So all potential negative effects of PTFE are not covered by food safety rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this manual, it is actually dishwasher safe

[t-fal manual](http://www.t-falusa.com/instructions-for-use/Products/Cookware,-and-Utensils/Pots-and-pans/Professional/csp/r-p-professional)

Answer (score 1):

It already looks like the coating has worn off significantly.  Without making any health claims (as I don't know what the impact of ingesting particles of T-fal coating), I don't think the dishwasher is going to do more damage, or release any more coating, than your use of inappropriate non-stick utensils already has.  ...maybe, just time for a new pot.

Answer (score 1):

Most non-stick can survive dishwashers anyway. If it's already scratched the scratches *might* get bigger but not necessarily. Depending on the metal underneath, there's a chance of it starting to flake off. Once that happens, it's pretty much gone.

The downside of the coating coming off is that food sticks worse than it would to a pan that was bare metal to start with. This may have something to do with intermediate surface treatments, and isn't a problem if you're using it for just boiling things in water.